# Writting custom XML tags in a custom XML formatter results in empty XML

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer, xml-formatting

I'm developing a custom XmlFormatter for a Web API app. I want it to treat "IEnumerable" elements diferently. Here is the code:

```
class CustomXmlFormatter : XmlMediaTypeFormatter
{
    public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, System.IO.Stream writeStream, System.Net.Http.HttpContent content, System.Net.TransportContext transportContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer;

            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                if ((typeof(IEnumerable<object>)).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                {

                    XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(writeStream);                       

                    writer.WriteStartElement("array");

                 /*   foreach (object o in (IEnumerable<object>)value)
                    {
                        serializer = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType());

                        serializer.Serialize(writeStream, o);
                    }*/

                    writer.WriteEndElement();

                }
                else
                {
                    serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);

                    serializer.Serialize(writeStream, value, xsn);
                }
            });
```

The idea is that, when it receives a List, it writes a tag of "array" and then serializes all the elements of the List. I've commented the foreach loop to simplify the question.

The problem is that, when the code is executed, it writes an empty XML (no "array" tag). How could i implement something like that?

Comment: Have you tried to flush writer?

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any Error? maybe in your array items have some value that not in valid in xml tag. and this happened make your xml data empty. you must check validation of items in array. all character not validation for xml tag name.
i think using this example is better:

```
 sr = new StreamWriter(filename, false, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                    //Write the header
                    sr.WriteLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>");
                    //Write our root node
                    sr.WriteLine("<" + node.Text + ">");
                    sr.WriteLine("array");
                    sr.WriteLine("</" + node.Text + ">");
```